# how to create a list of span for a given array

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I have an object which looks like that:

```
var users = ['user1', 'user2'];
```

For this object I would like to create a list of span like that:

```
"<span>user1</span><span>user2</span>"
```

I did try the following code

```
$('<span/>').text(users);
```

but it does not work properly, any ideas?

Comment: pkurek: see the tags and third code line

Answer (score 8):

This would work:

```
var users = ['user1', 'user2'];

$.each(users, function() {
    $("<span>", { text : this }).appendTo("body");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `users` should contain strings only, try this:

```
var users = ['user1', 'user2'];
for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    $("<span />").text(users[i]).appendTo("body");
};
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/p3EBy/)

Answer (score 2):

You also can use the `Array.map` method:

```
['user1', 'user2'].map(
    function(a){
        $('<span/>').html(a).appendTo($('body')); return a;
    }
);
```

Or even shorter:

```
$(['user1','user2'].map(function(a){return '<span>'+a+'</span>'}).join(''))
 .appendTo('body');
```

Or even `Array.filter` ;)

```
['user1', 'user2'].filter(
    function(a){
        $('<span/>').html(a).appendTo($('body')); return true;
    }
);
```

Or `jQuery.each` on a jQuery object derived from the Array

```
$(['user1', 'user2']).each(
    function(i,a){
        $('<span/>').html(a).appendTo($('body')); return true;
    }
);
```